# How to add conditions inside $lte?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection:

```js
   @Prop({ type: Number, required: true, default: 0 })
   have:number;
   @Prop({ type: Boolean, required: false, default: null })
   unstable?: boolean;
   @Prop({ type: Number, required: false, default: null })
   max?: number;
```

I need to filter the selection according to this principle.
If unstable === true, then do not select, if it is equal to false or null, then ignore the filter
The second have condition must be less than max, but only if max !== null otherwise ignore this filter

Also, both of these conditions must pass, i.e. if the record does not match for some condition, then we do not add it to the selection

Everything is clear with the first condition, it's easy to check if unstable !== true, then ignore
But in the second case, I can not normally design a filter. I think I'm doing everything right, but it doesn't work.

In general, this is what I came up with

```js
       {
         $and:[
           {
             unstable: {
               $ne: true
             },
           },
           {
             have: {
               $lte: {
                 cond: { // tried to write $cond as well, doesn't swear at anything, but there is no result
                   if: {
                     max: { $eq: null },
                   },
                   then: Infinity,
                   else: '$max', // tried to use Infinity here too, silence too
                 },
               },
             },
           },
         ],
       }
```

my logic is like this:

```
have <= (max === null ? Infinity : max)
```

also tested this option and it works

```
have: {
   $lte: Infinity
}
```

p.s.
Data example

```
  {
    id: 1,
    max: 10,
    have: 1,
    unstable: null,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    max: 10,
    have: 10,
    unstable: null,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    max: null,
    have: 1,
    unstable: null,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    max: null,
    have: 1,
    unstable: true,
  },
```

expected output ids: 1 and 3

id 2 not included, because have >== max
id 4 not included, because unstable === true

p.s.s.
https://mongoplayground.net/p/MriDNX6U7El

Comment: It will be better if you post a sample collection and expected output.

Comment: ok Thanks, @Roman. can you please add the expected output json?

Comment: @RajeshSenapati i dont neet to format output, i need only select filter.

Comment: documents 1 and 3 must be in query result

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/MmF0FLuYXyw . Is this what you want?

Comment: @RajeshSenapati no of course) did you read my question?

Comment: @RajeshSenapati i have add filter example in question

Comment: According to your code, id 2 is included, because `have: 10` is less or **equal** to `max: 10`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yes, you are right, but the problem is that nothing is returned as a result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
db.collection.find({
   unstable: { $ne: true },
   $expr: {
      $cond: {
         if: { $eq: ["$max", null] },
         then: true,
         else: { $lte: ["$have", "$max"] }
      }
   }
})
```

Or a bit shorter:

```
db.collection.find({
   unstable: { $ne: true },
   $expr: { $lte: ["$have", { $ifNull: ["$max", MaxKey()] }] }
})
```

Maybe [MaxKey](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#minkey-and-maxkey) is not available in your client, then you can use

```
db.collection.find({
   unstable: { $ne: true },
   $expr: { $lte: ["$have", { $ifNull: ["$max", true] }] }
})
```

because according [Ascending/Descending Sort](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#ascending-descending-sort) a boolean value is always greater than any numeric value.

Don't mistake the [Comparison Query Operators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/query-comparison/#comparison-query-operators) with [Comparison Expression Operators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/#comparison-expression-operators). The Comparison Query Operators are used in `find` directly, the Comparison Expression Operators are used in Aggregation Pipelines and `$expr` documents.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I broke my head while trying different options xD

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$project` for compare the fields same `document`. Try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      isCorrect: {
        "$cond": {
          "if": ["$max",null],
          "then": true,
          "else": {
            "$lte": ["$have","$max"]
          }
        }
      },
      doc: "$$ROOT"// for get the whole documents
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      isCorrect: true
    }
  }
])
```

Link mongo playground at [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eAnVLWspnbC)

Comment: What is the reason for `doc: "$$ROOT"`? If you like to add a field, then use `$set` (or the alias `$addFields`)

Comment: `doc: "$$ROOT"` help you get old document because `$project` only return those fields that will be get, in example if not have `doc: "$$ROOT"`, result only has `isCorrect` field.

Comment: That's the reason I suggest `$set` - would be simpler.

Comment: Thanks @WernfriedDomscheit, `$set` is better than `$project` in this case if i use aggregate.